# Not writing "var" before new variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I am just learning JavaScript, and I don't understand why the following code doesn't produce an error:

```
myTest = 5;
function addFifteen(num) {
    return num+15;
}
document.write(addFifteen(myTest));
```

Why do I not need "var" before "myTest"? If it runs without "var", what is the purpose of writing that?

Comment: equivalent to *globalObject*.myTest ... in a browser, that would be `window.myTest` ... this is Javascript 101, something you should learn in the first lesson :p - read [some Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description)

Comment: You can use 'use strict' and run JS in strict mode.
To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not specify a `var` before the variable, it is still valid javascript. This is why it does not produce an error. However, as a best practice, you should avoid this, because variables thus declared get tagged to the global scope `window`.

Having too many variables / functions thus declared is said to "pollute" your global scope and isn't considered good programming practice.

[There is a more thorough explanation about this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)